# Node finishes process without Firestore responses

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im using @google-cloud/firestore v0.11.2.

With this code:

```
const db = new Firestore({
  projectId: serviceAccount.project_id,
  credentials: {
    private_key: serviceAccount.private_key,
    client_email: serviceAccount.client_email
  }
})
db.collection('users').doc('xxxxxxx').get()
  .then(us => {
    console.log('here!')
    return us.data()
  })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.log)
```

The node process just ends without waiting for the response.
Nothing is printed in the console.

Nothing throws errors. I even added a process.on('error') but it's never called.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Where did you get the code for that constructor?  It doesn't look anything like what's presented in the API docs.  https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.11.x/Firestore#Firestore

Comment: That's how firebase-admin instantiates @google-cloud/firestore.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/master/src/firestore/firestore.ts

Comment: If you read carefully there, that's not the only code path (and certainly not the typical case) that will init the SDK.  Have you considered simply using the publicly documented constructor?

Comment: Thanks Doug! Apparently my problem had to do with the yarn.lock file. Everything is working now.